# .Net : Arranging Many Windows Forms on Screens

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

**Issue :** 
Is there any efficient way to arrange many independent Windows Forms in .Net ? 
I have to display many forms at the same time in my application.
It is a graphic charting application, and the number of forms depends of what the user wants, so it has to be dynamic.
Is it possible to arrange it like with MDI Layout ?

**Example :** 
For example, if user chooses 12 output chart forms, I would like to have them auto-arranged 4x3 on the default screen. Ideally, User could even choose many target screens among the monitors he has.

**Why not use MDI :** 
I do NOT want MDI, since my application is multi-screen and I want to leave the opportunity to the user to put his external output chart windows scattered over different screens wherever he wants.
But I would though like to have a default arrangement of output windows, **without calculating manually** screen and forms width/heights by dividing and stuff (Already doing this, it's a real pain). I would like to spare myself this ant-work and focus on business logic.

**What I am looking for  :**
If somebody knows an open source library or tool or cool method that could be great.

By the way, I found a very useful and handy tool that could help people having the same needs I am formulating here : It is named [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap), but unfortunately  code is not Open Source

PS : Again, I Know how to do it "by hand" and assign monitors to forms. It is not the kind of answers I am looking for.

ThanX

Comment: is it really so difficult to calculate form dimensions from number of forms and available screens?

Comment: Just a thought: forms can be child controls to other non-form controls, so you can have a set of panels hosting forms.  Note that the forms lose some behaviour though, not sure on the specifics, but it's a possibility.  Then you can add your own code to allow users to detach forms from the dock and have them become normal windows.

Comment: @Axarydax : I am already doing that but I would like to have a more flexible and straightforward solution, as I said, I want to focus on business logic and avoid reinventing the wheel. At least 70% of development effort made globally is redundant and somebody somewhere has already spent time doing the same thing.

Comment: @Adam : your proposition violates one of my coding paradigms : Never use more components that what's needed. 9 times out of 10 user will indeed detach/rearrange forms and the Panel will end up "orphanized", and I am left with a supplementary element to handle not knowing what to do with it. IMHO it is cleaner to drop the forms and let user rearrange them through screens if he feels like

Comment: Possibly use a docking framework: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/ However it sounds like you don't want a docking host, but the logic to windows to snap to screen dimensions and with each other - so I won't propose it as an answer.

Comment: @Adam : Thank you for your relevant proposition you seem very well informed. we already work with dockpanelsuite, it is really powerful but it is heavy and the documentation is not clear enough and comprehensive; and, as you stated it, I would prefer to avoid MDI docking, because we have users with 9+ monitors and MDI is really not suitable in this situation. If I do not find something already done, i'll just code it and publish it Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against multiple forms, and go with something that's more usable, like a single form with segmented panels or other containers for sections. Multiple forms have too many usability issues, like not appearing in the task bar, overlapping, etc.

I know this is not the answer you want, but I'm encouraging you to think in different directions. Usability is crucial with complex data and multiple views.

Comment: As I stated, My App is a Multiscreen Application, and I cannot force the user to use the panel over different displays -> usability issues

Answer (score 0):

it's something I'm also looking for
[image]

Mql5 + C# expert advisor produces number of forms equal to a number of fin symbols one trying to trade, so something like a docker for 2,3,.. N forms is very welcome